# Webpack 4 - getting async 'splitChunks' in SSR by name / module ID

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, webpack-4

I'm trying to mimic the effects of [react-universal-component](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component) in Webpack 4.

**TL;DR - I'd like a way to dump `<link>` and `<script>` tags in the SSR HTML render containing *all* the CSS/JS chunks that the client would have requested on any given route, that the server instead loaded synchronously.**

Using [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable), a typical async React component looks like this in both the server and client bundles:

```js
const Logo = loadable({
  loader: () => import("./logo/logo"),
  loading: ()  => <div>Loading...</div>,
  modules: ["./logo/logo"],
  webpack: () => [(require as any).resolveWeak("./logo/logo")],
});
```

On the server, I'm using `<Loadable.Capture>` to get the module names used to render the route:

```js
// Modules used to render this route
const modules: string[] = [];

// Generate the HTML from our React tree.
const components = (
  <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
    <StaticRouter location={ctx.request.url} context={routeContext}>
      <Root />
    </StaticRouter>
  </Loadable.Capture>
);
```

Which works fine - `modules` for the `/logo` route contains:

> ['./logo/logo']

What I now need to do is somehow find `./logo/logo` in the Webpack stats (which is available in my server environment as a variable passed in to the middleware, or as a static JSON file generated by Webpack) and correlate that to the generated chunk either by the module ID returned by the `require.resolveWeak()` call... or (preferably) directly on the `./logo/logo` import name.

This is where I'm stuck. None of the 'universal component' NPM modules mentioned above are yet compatible with Webpack 4, and techniques that relied on the previous CommonChunksPlugin are defunct.

Is there an example anywhere of consuming the Webpack stats to find the relevant chunk file name based on the string that was passed to `import()`?

Comment: Have you found solution to this problem? Does reactql solve it? https://github.com/leebenson/reactql